# Windows service wrong application data path

Tags: c#, service

I'm writing a `Windows Service` and I'm trying to cache some logs in `MyDocuments` using the common syntax:

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);`
```

But the service would crash and by looking over the `Event Viewer` it turns out that the `GetFolderPath`

is outputting
`C:\Windows\system32\EPiA\EPiAServiceLog.txt`

instead of `C:\Windows\Users\<Username>\Documents\EPiA\EPiAServiceLog.txt`

What is that supposed to mean?

Comment: MyDocuments is the reference to the current user Documents directory. Now in your Windows Service what is the user running the Service?

Comment: It means that you did not configure the service to use a *specific* user account.  So you get the System account, there is not a lot of "my" in that account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default a Windows Service does not run as an interactive user account (not using the same credentials as the logged in user).

The path you are getting, therefore, is correct. You could get a user path if you configure the service to run as a specific user (which need not be the same as the logged-in user).